Contact Report with all data
We need a report or a file with all data on all contacts in Civi. This should include assigned tags (e.g., major donors, etc.). In other words, everything that has ever been entered. Is that possible?

Do you also need contributions, memberships, activities, notes, etc?

Yes! I can´t find a solution.
